# How to Reset Date/Time M500 Sport DV Camera?

Tags: camera

I recently bought a M500 Sport DV Cam. I am unable to reset/change Date and Time. According to Manual, Cam will create SportDV.txt file in SDCard and we can change Date Time from SportDV.txt file.

But My Cam is not creating any SportDV.txt file. It only creates Two folders Data (which contains an empty base.dat file) and DCIM (Which contains videos and Images).

I tried to create file Manually, but It doesn't change Date/Time. I also tried different methods like creating files with name times.txt, time.txt, timeset.txt, tag.txt, settime.txt but nothing works.

I am unable to change Date and Time. It always shows Year 2158 instead of 2015.
Sample Date: 2158/8/14 22:10:22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried everything and failed. But I found the solution.
Open Notepad and Copy & Paste

```
SPORTS DV
UPDATE:N
        FORMAT
EV:6
CTST:100
SAT:100
AWB:0
SHARPNESS:100
AudioVol:1
QUALITY:0
LIGHTFREQ:0
AE:0
RTCDisplay:1
year:2014
month:7
date:7
hour:16
minute:11
second:0
-------------------------------
Exposure(EV)
    0 ~ 12, def:6
Contrast(CTST)
    1 ~ 200, def:100
Saturation(SAT)
    1 ~ 200, def:100
White Balance(AWB)
    0 ~ 3, def:0, 0(auto), 1(Daylight), 2(Cloudy), 3(Fluorescent)
Sharpness
    1 ~ 200, def:100
AudioVol
    0 ~ 2, def:1, 0:Max  1:Mid  2:Min
QUALITY
    0 ~ 2, def:0, 0:High  1:Middle  2:Low
LIGHTFREQ
    0 ~ 1, def:0, 0:60Hz  1:50Hz
AUTO EXPOSURE(AE)
    0 ~ 2, def:0, 0:Average  1:Center  2:Spot
RTCDisplay
    0 ~ 1, def:1, 0:Off  1:On
year
    2012 - 2038, def:2013
month
    01 - 12, def:1
date
    01 - 31, def:1
hour
    00 - 23, def:0
minute
    01 - 59, def:0
second
    01 - 59, def:0
```

Set Update:N to Update:Y, 
Change year, month, date ,
**and save the file with the name SportDV and Encoding to UTF-8**

Answer (score 2):

For versions that have a time.bat file putting a N at the end of the timestamp in the time.txt file removes the timestamp from the video, ie time.txt:

2015.11.13 20:13:31 N

Answer (score 0):

i have the more recent version of the m500 mini camera that doesnt use the sportdv.txt file
It looks same physically as earlier one, same leds, same decals but it instead after being reset has a time.bat file in the root of the card. executing this on a windows machine produced a file called time.txt except the format of this batch file doesnt work, 
i edited the time.txt file and restated the camera and it worked after following andys format from his posting on the dx.com site

> choose edit and then make sure you replace the (probably nonsense format) contents with 2015.11.13 20:13:31 - in this case that's YYYY.MM.DD HH:MM:SS click save. turn off/eject the camera. Power up now not connected to PC and make a short capture. Now when you check the content the date/time will hopefully be right?

afaik there is no updated firmware for this version of the camera to change from 3 min files or hide the time/date text :-(

Comment: On mine the format of `/Time.txt` was one line: `2017-01-01 10:00:00`. This format isn't nonsense - it's ISO8601 `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. The line was terminated by two nulls, so the entire contents of `/Time.txt` was `"2017-01-01 10:00:00\0\0"` in C notation. Set the time by modifying the `/Time.txt`, updating the timestamp and changing the two nulls to `\r\n` (the MSDOS / Windows line terminator), but note the `10:00` - it will add that to whatever time you enter. Boot the camera, take a photo, and it will set the time from the file and revet the contents of the file back to how you found it.